# Error CS1929 when i try to make a searchbar in a listview can someone check my code for errors?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin, searchbar

This is my code, i get error CS1929. i am trying to make a searchbar in a listview. Can someone check my code for fixes and post what code i need to use, or if there is another way to make a searchbar? i neeeeeeed Help!

this is my Xaml.cs code:

```
namespace App2
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    List<Kontakter> kontakter = new List<Kontakter>
    {
        new Kontakter
        {
        Fuldenavn = "Anja Birkelund (ANBI)",
        Tlfnr = 24212504
        },
        new Kontakter
        {
            Fuldenavn = "Morten Jensen (MOJ)",
            Tlfnr = 24838149
        },
        new Kontakter
        {
            Fuldenavn = "Thomas Duvall Pedersen (TPD)",
            Tlfnr = 61706767
        },
        new Kontakter
        {
            Fuldenavn = "Svend-Erik Dejbjerg (SD)",
            Tlfnr = 20116644
        }
    };

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        NameslistView.ItemsSource = kontakter;
    }

    private void MainSearchBar_SearchButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var keyword = MainSearchBar.Text;

        NameslistView.ItemsSource =
            kontakter.Where(name => name.Contains(keyword));
    }
}
```

}

this is my Xmal code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App2"
         x:Class="App2.MainPage">

<StackLayout>
    <SearchBar x:Name="MainSearchBar" SearchButtonPressed="MainSearchBar_SearchButtonPressed" />

    <ListView x:Name="NameslistView" HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Fuldenavn}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Tlfnr}" />
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: You're almost there. Try [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/28899/listview-search-bar)

Comment: When you get that error (any error actually), it should stop you on a specific line, could you tell us which line that is?

Comment: Your list contains object not string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way:

```
private void MainSearchBar_SearchButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var keyword = MainSearchBar.Text;
    NameslistView.ItemsSource = kontakter.Where(obj =>(obj.Fuldenavn.Contains(keyword) || obj.Tlfnr.ToString().Contains(keyword)));
}
```

PS:

Modify your code in XMAL:

```
<StackLayout>
    <SearchBar x:Name="MainSearchBar" SearchButtonPressed="MainSearchBar_SearchButtonPressed" />
    <ListView x:Name="NameslistView" HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Fuldenavn}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Tlfnr}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Otherwise, the two label will overlap.

My test:

[image]

#### Update

If you want to show all the item after click the cancel button , assign the Event **TextChanged**

```
<SearchBar x:Name="MainSearchBar" SearchButtonPressed="MainSearchBar_SearchButtonPressed"  TextChanged="MainSearchBar_TextChanged"/>
```

Code behind:

```
private void MainSearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewTextValue == string.Empty)
    {
        NameslistView.ItemsSource = kontakter.Where(name => (name.Fuldenavn.Contains("")));
    }
}
```

### Update2

if you want to search verbatim ,just modify the event `TextChanged` to observe the e.NewTextValue.

```
private void MainSearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
     NameslistView.ItemsSource = kontakter.Where(obj => (obj.Fuldenavn.Contains(e.NewTextValue)|| obj.Tlfnr.ToString().Contains(e.NewTextValue)));  
}
```

Comment: it just look like this now https://gyazo.com/745e0aebcdfe42c715345fb763fdafb1 @Cole Xia

Comment: @KristianF is this before or after you click the search button?

Comment: it looks like this all the time before i search and after @Cole Xia

Comment: @KristianF attach the code how you define the class `Kontakter`

Comment: I can search on people like "Anja" and one comes on the list but i cant see the name Anja now @Cole Xia

Comment: namespace App2
    {
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public class Kontakter
        {
        public string Fuldenavn { get; set; }
        public int Tlfnr { get; set; }
        }

    }
}

@Cole Xia

Comment: I have uploaded my test, tell me what's the differences bewtween you.

Comment: is this correct?

`   ['code'] <StackLayout>
        <SearchBar x:Name="MainSearchBar" SearchButtonPressed="MainSearchBar_SearchButtonPressed" />

        <ListView x:Name="NameslistView" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Fuldenavn}" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Tlfnr}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>`

@Cole Xia

Comment: @KristianF You miss the node DataTemplate. (which contains the ViewCell)

Comment: Ma man, it works! but after i seached how can i get the full list agian i dont if you know what i mean but TY for the help! @Cole Xia

Comment: exactlig what i ment :D I love you <3 ! no homo @Cole Xia

Comment: @KristianF oh i love you too but please accept my answer first :)

Comment: Can you help me agian? @Cole Xia

Comment: @KristianF what's your problem

Comment: i want it to look like googles searchbar, so when i type one letter fx "a"  all names with "a" comes up. hard to tell exactly what i mean but hope you can help? @Cole Xia

Comment: @KristianF you mean the search result comes out according to the texts you are inputing ? a comes all contain a ,an comes all contain an ,the result keep observing your inputing letter one by one？

Comment: after i searched on a name my list is not sorted anymore can you help? @Cole Xia      

            var sorted = Kontakter.OrderBy(x => x.Fuldenavn)
                                  .ToList();

            NameslistView.ItemsSource = sorted;

Comment: @KristianF Could you create a new thread to ask your question? because this problem is not related to the origin issue.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ query must be like

```
NameslistView.ItemsSource =
            kontakter.Where(obj => obj.Fuldenavn.Contains(keyword));
```

Comment: try @Cole Xia answer it is more complete and accurate.